# How to add font awesome license keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, font-awesome

Does anyone know how can I install license keys for FontAwesome version 6 in my .NET Core MVC project?

I have tried to find any help articles but didn't come across any. I recently got a license key from a client to use Font Awesome 6. Currently I have v 4 installed as a nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome/4.7.0

How do I add the license key and upgrade the version in my visual studio project.

Ex: One of the icons I want to use is below
https://fontawesome.com/icons/burger-fries?s=light&f=classic

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome 6 is published using `npm` or `yarn`; Not Nuget. You have to install it using one of those 2 tools and probably run a task runner to put the relevant files in you wwwroot folder, if needed. (Webpack, gulp, ...)

In order to be able to install and update FontAwesome, you need to register a private registry:

```
npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" FONT-AWESOME-PACKAGE-FONT-AWESOME-PACKAGE-TOKEN
```

`FONT-AWESOME-PACKAGE-FONT-AWESOME-PACKAGE-TOKEN` is your access key provided by your client. Keep it safe. Do not share it, ever. Do not check it into version control.

Two alternative ways are listed in the official docs: https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages

After you're set up, you can install the package using

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro
```